# Replacing Line if it Matches Line from Other File in Nested [While, IF, Sed] Statement

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I have a 17k lines-long file `F1` with 8 fields per line formatted as follows:

```
id1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8
id2 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8
```

The second file `F2` content unfolds in a single field per line (one column)

```
id1
uuuuuuu
bbbbbbb
aaaaaaa
id2
ttttttt
qqqqqqq
...
```

The lines from `F2` should be replaced with the lines from `F1` if there is a match. Thought the weird while loop below could work but, needless to say, it returns all the lines from `F2` per change made. Or probably Bash may have other magical tools that could do the trick, perhaps?

```
while read id1 id2 id3 id4 id5; do
        while read ID; do
                if [[ $ID == "$id1" ]]; then
                        sed "s/$ID/$id1 $id2 $id5 $id4/" F2 && break
                fi
        done < F2
done < F1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'NR == FNR {line[$1] = $0; next} $1 in line {$0 = line[$1]} 1' F1 F2
```

1. `NR == FNR {line[$1] = $0; next}` -- while reading `F1`, store each line keyed by the first field
2. `$1 in line {$0 = line[$1]}` -- we're reading `F2` now: if the first field is in the `line` array, substitute the array value as the current record.
3. `1` -- print the current record.